# How to create a MySQL create function?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a simple function like below to do an easy task:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION f(key TEXT, str TEXT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    IF LOCATE(key, str) > 0 THEN
        RETURN 1;
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

But I got an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key T
EXT, str TEXT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    IF LOCATE(key, str) > 0 THEN
        R' at line 1
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What's the error? Please think about how people might go about diagnosing this problem before submitting your question.

Comment: I have a feeling that `key` is blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function has a syntax error because `key` is a reserved word in MySql. Solution: rename the parameter or put `key` inside backticks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f(`key` TEXT, str TEXT) RETURNS INT
```

Answer (score 1):

key is a keyword in mysql, put it between ` or use different name.